# Instance of a class delgate returning info to main form

Tags: c#, class, delegates

I am currently using the tweeinvi twitter library to filter tweets. I have a main form which creates which creates a instance of the class TwitterAuthentication. On creating the constructor handles the authentication process. From the main form i then create a filter for the word hello and try to return any matches from this filtered stream back to the main form for logging in a simple text window.

So main form bits -

```
private void authenticate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TwitterAuthentication user = new TwitterAuthentication();
        twitter_user.Text = user.username();

        string UserTxt = user.ToString();


        user.set_filter(log_output_update);


    }
    public void log_output_update(string s) //int y)
    {
        {
            string z = "[def]";

            //if (y == 0) { z = "[SYS] "; }
            //if (y == 1) { z = "[IN] "; }
            //if (y == 2) { z = "[OUT] "; }
            //if (y == 3) { z = "[**ERROR**] It may be Phils Coding! Error - "; }

            string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

            //if (y == 0) { log_output_window.SelectionColor = Color.White; }
            //if (y == 1) { log_output_window.SelectionColor = Color.Blue; }
            //if (y == 2) { log_output_window.SelectionColor = Color.Green; }
            //if (y == 3) { log_output_window.SelectionColor = Color.Red; }

            log_output_window.AppendText(z + time + " " + s + System.Environment.NewLine);
            log_output_window.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
```

and the full class ( ihave blanked out the credentials with x) -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Models;
using System.Drawing;


public class TwitterAuthentication
{
public delegate void Callback_Log_Tweet(string x);
public TwitterAuthentication()
{

    IAuthenticationContext _authContext;
    var appCredentials = new TwitterCredentials("x", "x");
    _authContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCredentials);



    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var Stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
            {
                Process.Start(_authContext.AuthorizationURL);

                //open pin box and enter pin
                SocialiFace_v2.PinAuth Pin = new SocialiFace_v2.PinAuth();
                Pin.ShowDialog();
                System.Console.WriteLine(Pin.Pin_Auth);
                var userCredentials = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(Pin.Pin_Auth, _authContext);
                Auth.SetCredentials(userCredentials);

                try
                {
                    var authenticateduser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Tweetinvi.Exceptions.TwitterNullCredentialsException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Authenticating");
                    return;
                }
            }
            //Callback_Log_Tweet("Logged In...."");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Authenticating2");
            return;
        }

    }
}

public string username()
{
    try
    {
        var authenticateduser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
        string handle = authenticateduser.Name;
        return handle;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error getting username");
        return null;
    }
}

public void set_filter(Callback_Log_Tweet x)
{
    var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
    stream.AddTrack("Hello");
    stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Send back to delgate, and to print output delegate
       x("A tweet containing 'Hello' has been found; the tweet is '" + args.Tweet + "'");

    };
}
```

Any assistance on passing this back would be great! Also if i want from the class to pass back any standard text outside the set_filter method how would this be achieved?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a Process class where the only way of communicating with the application is using Standard Input/Output.  It would be better to use a HttpRequest where you can communicate directly with the server.

Comment: @jdweng Using an Http request limits the amount of requests i can make, where this is a neater solution and the stream will match any tweets matching my filter in realtime as they are published.

Comment: Why would the limits be any different.  When the connection is made the server only get the IP of the client which is no different between the httprequest and the  tweeinvi twitter library.

Comment: @jdweng Ok i thought not using streams and making requests directly there was a limit on number os results from twitter an lmited, using the request method rather than stream. Also if making an http request how do i contunaully make that request to get live data? Anyother feedback you can give would be apreciated.

Comment: @jdweng having check, there is limits on the GET and POST https request methods and the Streaming API has less limits. Therfore using the streaming API make sense in this application.

Comment: If you have an API then you should be calling the API methods directly using DllImport instead of using process if the methods in the dll are documented.  You must have a dll that has a main method so it can be run from the command line.  If the dll has other public methods they can be called using DllImport.

Comment: @jdweng sorry you have lost me now withint that. I am fairly new to programming, however, i know i can make this work if i keep it all in my main code, but as the application is growing i need to split out to more classes. Is there a way to pass this info back to a logging method in the main application from a class, such in the way i have done?

Comment: Do you have the documentation on the API?  Normally the will give all the methods inside the API and the parameter list to use to call the methods.

Comment: @jdweng the Tweetinvi Methods? or Twitter API? I have both, but using the Tweetinvi library is so much easier and its a great library. The methods im  calling im calling correctly. The parameter is fine, i aslo knwo all this info. All i cant do is get the info from the class back to the main application.

Comment: What you are saying is call the API from the command line is easier that calling the methods.  If you have the source code then look at the main method.  The main method will give you an example of how to call the methods.  You want your cake and have your pie too.  You want to be able to call the library easily and get the results easily.  You can't have both.

Comment: @jdweng no im not sayign that in the slightest. Im actually asking about how to pass info from a instance class back to a main application so the data recived can be output as text in a text box. When i get a result/matching tweet how do i use an instance of the class to keep that API out of the main body of the application. There must be a way to do this? If i get a result, how do i pass that back to the main application, or should i structure this in a different manner? I am not saying anything about command line I know how to call the main methods

Comment: Starting the process is simple using a command line option (which is what you are doing using the PROCESS CLASS), but getting the data out serially is complicated. You have two different processes and need to connect the output of one process to the input of the other process which is done serially.    If you call the method as a function you have the option of setting/getting data though the parameter list (or the return value) which is easy, but you may have to call a number of methods which is harder than the command line option.  You want both easy options.

Comment: It depends if your API is managed of unmanaged.  Hopefully it is managed.  Then you just use the menu Project : Add Existing Item : Browse to the dll of the TwitterAuthentication.  Then add the using statement (the library class) to the top of the module.  The TwitterAuthentication dll will the get copied to the bin folder of your c# application.  Adding the using statement then connects the dll which is a reference in the Solution Explorer to the outside dll.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your help, I was after nothing more complicated than using an Action statement to return the string that i needed from the class back to the main form. Ill post the code shorlty that worked for me.